# Merging two arrays of hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I’m very close to solving a project I’ve been working on for a while but can’t seem to figure this out.

```
array1 = [{:new_listing => "1", :item => "apple"}, {:new_listing => "2", :item => "bannana"}]
array2 = [{:height => "10"}, {:height => "12"}]
```

How do I merge them so it is

```
[{:new_listing => "1", :item => "apple", :height => "10" },
 {:new_listing => "2", :item => "bannana", :height => "12"}]
```

The order of each arrays are aligned, and should be the same size. Some values of `array2` will be `{:height => nil}`.

Answer (score 1):

> The order of each arrays are aligned, and should be the same size.

That's exactly the description of the [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) method.

> ```
> zip(arg, ...) → an_array_of_array
> ```
>
> Takes one element from *enum* and merges corresponding elements from each *args*.

Likewise, merging hashes is done with [`merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Hash.html#method-i-merge)

```
array1.zip(array2).map { |x, y| x.merge(y) }
```

Comment: To this day, I still don't understand why passing a block to `zip` behaves like `each` and not like `map`. I literally have never once wanted to iterate over the zipped array, it is always either `map` or some other higher-level iterator such as `select` or `inject`.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
array1.map {|x| x.merge!(array2.shift) }
```

use map/each as per your requirement

Answer (score -1):

Below solution should work for you:

```
array1 = [{:new_listing=> "1", :item=> "apple"}, {:new_listing=> "2", :item=> "bannana"}]
array2 = [{:height=> "10"},{:height => "12"}]

array2.each_with_index { |hash, index| array1[index] = array1[index].merge(hash) }

puts array1
# [{:new_listing=>"1", :item=>"apple", :height=>"10"}, {:new_listing=>"2", :item=>"bannana", :height=>"12"}]
```